# How to only allow smart contract erc-721 airdrops to be from one address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, nft

Here is my testnet contract: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa63a032185452a2ab7da24a26ca9342e78e799a7

All i need is to understand what to do to enable 50 airdrops to be done but only from my wallet address.

(Just need to make sure no one else can go to 'write contract' on etherscan and send an airdrop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition verifying that the `msg.sender` is your address. I see that you're already using the `ownable` pattern (probably the OpenZeppelin implementation), so you can use this.

When you deployed the contract, the constructor assigned your address to the `_owner` variable. There's also the `onlyOwner()` modifier that throws an exception (effectively reverting the transaction) if the transaction was not sent from the `_owner` address.

So you can update your `airdrop()` function to use the `onlyOwner()` modifier.

```
function airdrop(bytes memory code) public onlyOwner() {
```

Then you'll be able to execute the `airdrop()` function only from the address that deployed the token *(or became a new owner through the `transferOwnership()` function)*.

If you execute the function from any other address, it will revert.

Comment: What do I need to do in order to airdrop to someone elses wallet in a way where it mints it straight to their wallet but I'm the one doing the transaction?

Comment: Your `airdrop()` calls `mintToSender()` which calls `_mint()`. This `_mint()` function accepts an `address` as the first argument, which is the target wallet that you want to mint the token. You'll need to update your `airdrop()` (or create a new function) to not call `mintToSender()`, but to call the `_mint()` directly, which you can use to specify the target wallet for the token to be minted to.